# Form not saving to model with two Foreign Keys - Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I'm having trouble saving my form to a model that has two foreign keys:

1. User who is submitting the form
2. The current price of the Crypto submitted.

The form values seem to through the AssetView but not being saved. Could anyone help to why they aren't saving. I've provided Models, Views, Form, HTML.

**Django Models**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class CryptoPrices(models.Model):
    symbol = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    current_price = models.FloatField(default=0.0)

class CryptoAssets(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    symbol = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    amount = models.FloatField(default=0.0)
    purchase_price = models.FloatField(default=0.0)
    crypto_prices = models.ForeignKey(CryptoPrices, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

**Django View**

```
from coinprices.forms import AssetForm

class AssetView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'coinprices/my-dashboard.html'

    def get(self, request):
        form_a = AssetForm(prefix='form_a')
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form_a': form_a})

    def post(self, request):
        form_a = AssetForm(request.POST, prefix='form_a')
        if form_a.is_valid():
            post = form_a.cleaned_data
            post.save()
            form = AssetForm()
            args = {'form': form}
            return render(request, self.template_name, args)

        args = {'form_a': form_a}
        return render(request, self.template_name, args)
```

**Django Form**

```
from coinprices.models import CryptoPrices

tickers = (('BTC', 'BTC'), ('ETH', 'ETH'))

class AssetForm(forms.ModelForm):

    symbol = forms.ChoiceField(choices=tickers, required=True, label='')
    amount = forms.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=20, required=True, label='')
    purchase_price = forms.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=20, required=True, label='')

    class Meta:
        model = CryptoAssets
        fields = (
            'symbol',
            'amount',
            'purchase_price'
        )
```

**HTML**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

    {% block head %}
    <title>My Dashboard</title>
    {% endblock %}

    {% block body %}
<br>
<div class="container">
      <h1>My Dashboard</h1>
        <p>
          <form method="post">
          {% csrf_token %}
          {{ form_a.as_p }}
          <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </p>
</div>
    {% endblock %}
```

**Errors**

```
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'save'
```

Comment: Are you sure `form_a.is_valid()` is true?

Comment: Also what is the point of `post = form_a.cleaned_data` and then calling `post.save()`?  Does that even work?  I thought `.save()` was a method on the form object itself, not on the cleaned_data dictionary.

Comment: Yes I've added a print statement and it is true

Comment: With the ```form_a.cleaned_data``` I'm getting the error ```AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'save'```, if I remove the ```.cleaned_data``` i get the error ```django.db.utils.IntegrityError: null value in column "crypto_prices_id" of relation "coinprices_cryptoassets" violates not-null constraint
```

Comment: If you're getting an error, why did you not mention that in the question?  Thats very important detail to leave out...

Comment: I've updated the question to add errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let me explain you the errors:

```
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'save'
```

This error happens because you are trying yo save this way:

```
post = form_a.cleaned_data
post.save()
```

That is wrong because cleaned_data is a dict, it contains the values of your form as a fieldname:value pairs.

The correct way is:

```
post = form_a.save()
```

The next error says that value of field crypto_prices is required but you are passing a null value.

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: null value in column "crypto_prices_id" of relation "coinprices_cryptoassets" violates not-null constraint
```

This happens because in your form AssetForm you are selecting only this fields:

```
fields = (
            'symbol',
            'amount',
            'purchase_price'
        )
```

Where is crypto_prices? The field is defined as required in your models.py in this line:

```
crypto_prices = models.ForeignKey(CryptoPrices, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

The solution: you need to include the field 'crypto_prices' in your forms or set it before save the form in AssetView. As this:

class AssetForm(forms.ModelForm):

```
symbol = forms.ChoiceField(choices=tickers, required=True, label='')
amount = forms.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=20, required=True, label='')
purchase_price = forms.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=20, required=True, label='')

class Meta:
    model = CryptoAssets
    fields = (
        'symbol',
        'amount',
        'purchase_price',
        'crypto_prices'
    )
```

Or this way:

```
class AssetView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'coinprices/my-dashboard.html'

    def get(self, request):
        form_a = AssetForm(prefix='form_a')
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form_a': form_a})

    def post(self, request):
        form_a = AssetForm(request.POST, prefix='form_a')
        if form_a.is_valid():
            post = form_a.save(commit=False)
            post.crypto_prices = CryptoPrices.objects.get(id=someid) # this way with object
            post.crypto_prices_id = 1 # or this way with a integer
            post.save()
            form = AssetForm()
            args = {'form': form}
            return render(request, self.template_name, args)

        args = {'form_a': form_a}
        return render(request, self.template_name, args)
```